# wget downloads an html instead of my file

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

I have uploaded a text file containing "hello world" to a site. The site created bellow link to download the file:

```
http://s8.picofile.com/d/8293527218/5b6a0e68-9956-43e2-94a5-4942a805db40/mmm
```

when I copy this link and paste it in Google chrome search bar of my laptop it simply downloads the file and everything is good. but when I download it in a remote cluster system (that I connect to it using ssh), using `wget link-address` it downloads a file named `mmm.html` that is different from my text file.

how can I use `wget` command in a remote Linux system to download the file and why does this problem happen?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of these file sharing sites is to generate a single link for a specific IP address, so when you generate the download link in your PC, it's only can be download with your PC's IP address, your remote linux system has another IP so picofile will redirect your remote request to the actual download package which is a HTML page and `wget` downloads it.

If you want to download this file from this file hosting with your remote machine you should generate the link using your remote machine too.

try terminal based browsers like `w3m`, `lynx`, etc; From your remote machine.

Answer (score 4):

[wget actually downloads your file...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JhEU.png)

The link you provided opened a webpage at picofile.com, mostly in arabic I presume, the direct download link to the "mmm" file was http://s8.picofile.com/d/8293527218/b9e0df57-217a-43bb-9e09-43ac5092b85a/mmm. Passing this URL to wget actually downloaded the file. That's common situation with most of these file hosting sites - the "sharing" url points to their website and the actual download link is hidden behind some javascript there. Often, the only way how to extract this link is starting a download via a browser and copying the download link from its download manager.

Comment: The language is Persian ;)

Comment: I actually stopped for a second to think if it could be Farsi, but found it statistically more probable to be Arabic... Not a good method to recognize languages, I know, moreover with this approach I should have been guessing Chinese :) Thanks for the correction though, it actually bothered me a little...